# Is it safe to use managed objects loaded in background by performBlock: in main thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm creating my managed object context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` concurrency type.

Also I'm using `performBlock:` selector to execute operations in background. So If I'm fetching some objects in background (in performBlock:), is it safe to use resulting managed objects in main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, no it is not safe to share `NSManagedObject` instances across threads no matter what concurrency type you are using.

However there is a [library](https://github.com/adam-roth/coredata-threadsafe) you can use to make your context(s) and object instances thread-safe.  With that you can pretty much ignore all the nonsense about ensuring thread isolation between contexts and focus your efforts on the things that matter, like building out the actual functionality of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but in my own experience I do it this way:  If you are *changing* the variables properties, do it inside `performBlock`.  I had one case where reading was causing some weird behavior, but in general it seems to be OK.  If you want to be extra safe, use `performBlock` every time you touch a managed object in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a different context for each thread as explained here [iOS Developer - Core data multithreading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1)

One way to implement is described at [Core Data - one context per thread implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264540/grand-central-dispatch-gcd-with-coredata/12039308#12039308)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should've search better, here is exactly my question & answer to it:
[Core Data's NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and sharing objects between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637921/core-datas-nsprivatequeueconcurrencytype-and-sharing-objects-between-threads)